# Cannot Find WXPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

When I run code all I get is a cannot import wx python. I put wx python in C:\Put a directory on PYTHONPATH here\Lib\site-packages . That does not seem to work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: can you post code and the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to properly install wxPython on your system using the appropriate installer binary for Windows, which you can download from [wxPython.org](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php)).

Answer (score 0):

Install wxpython based on your system requirements(32/64 bit) and also your python version from http://wxpython.org/download.php and try running your code. Dont directly put wxpython directory into Python\Lib\site-packages, if u install it, it will be there automatically.